# splice удаляет первый элемент все время

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Почему splice удаляет все время первый элемент массива?

```
onClickDelete = (index, type) => {
    // type - объект с массивом
    // index - индекс объекта в массиве
    let element = this.props.myobject[type][index] // Объект массива на который кликнули
    let data = {...this.props.myobject} // Создаем копию объекта в котором лежат объекты с массивами
    data[type].splice(element, 1) // удаляем из массива эллемент по которому был сделан клик
    this.props.changeSetDataAction(data) // Action который обновляет редюсер
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может заменить эти строчки кода?

```
data[type].splice(element, 1)
```

на такое?

```
data[type].splice(index,1) // ??
```